# Having trouble with Texture Paint

Tags: texture-painting

i'm new to the blender and i don't really understand why is this happening
[image]

[image]

[image: when i'm trying to paint these rhombuses its paints a handle too]

when i'm trying to paint these rhombuses its paints a handle too

UV Map:
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the UV map from the UV Editor? It is possible your uvs overlap and so painting in one spot also affects faces elsewhere.

Comment: okay lemme edit it, i will add a screenshot of UV map

Comment: Your parts are overlapping so that is why your paint is affecting both areas, rearrange your map to keep everything no overlapping.